# How to distribute amcl's particles all over the map?

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when you first launch Rviz with particle cloud, the particles is gathered around the robot model, I wonder how to make those particles distribute all over my map? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400644/how-to-distribute-amcl%27s-particles-all-over-the-map?/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2022-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The amcl node provides a service named "global_localization". It is documented on the wiki page for the amcl node. You can call the service from code or from the terminal command line.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2022-05-15**:
Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much.